# Laravel Mail Listener (Before Send - Ability to Cancel)

Tags: laravel-4, listeners

Is there a way to use Laravel's "Event" class to run some code before every email is sent? I'd also like the ability to cancel the `Mail::send();`.

Of course I could do this before I send an email:

```
Event::fire('email.beforeSend');
```

And then I could listen this way:

```
Event::listen('email.beforeSend', function()
{
    //my code here
});
```

The problem with this is that I have to remember to run `Event::fire()` which I'd rather not do. In my case I'm bouncing the email address against an unsubscribe list to make sure that I don't send any spam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Laravel 5 you can listen to the `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` event and `return false` if you want to cancel sending the message.

Add this to your `EventServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
            'App\Listeners\CheckEmailPreferences',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Here is my event listener at `App\Listeners\CheckEmailPreferences`

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class CheckEmailPreferences
{
    public function handle( MessageSending $event )
    {
        //if app is in prod and we don't want to send any emails
        if(App::environment() === 'production' && ! env('SEND_MAIL_TO_CUSTOMERS')){
            return false;
        }

        //you can check if the user wants to receive emails here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out based on your example. I did note you are using env() instead of config() function. According to the docs, env doesn't work outside of the config classes, if you use config:cache

Comment: I don't think I use that but you can make it a config variable instead to meet those needs and use the env() function for your config variable

Comment: is there a way to filter out emails if multiple emails are provided? Like on development I only want to send emails to myself

Comment: @NielsLucas you can return the `$event` after manipulating it to change the recipients. I have not tried myself but should work in theory

Comment: @MikeHarrison thanks for your reply, I did try that. But there is so much data in that object + a lot of private properties that I cant access. I gave up after an hour or so. Frustrated, cause I really thought I could make it work.

Comment: @NielsLucas you can access the `$event->message` property which is a `\Swift_Message`. Then use the `$event->message->getTo()` to see current recipients and `$event->message->setTo()` to set new or change recipients

Answer (score 6):

Laravel's Mail class fires `mailer.sending` as part of the sending process.

```
protected function sendSwiftMessage($message)
{
    if ($this->events)
    {
        $this->events->fire('mailer.sending', array($message));
    }

    if ( ! $this->pretending)
    {
        $this->swift->send($message, $this->failedRecipients);
    }
    elseif (isset($this->logger))
    {
        $this->logMessage($message);
    }
}
```

You could catch this event and adjust the `$message` object, or you could likely prevent sending by calling `Mail::pretend();` within your event handler.

Comment: Interesting. So my listener would look like `Event::listen('mailer.sending', function(){});`? Not familiar with `Mail::pretend();` I'm guessing this does the same thing as `'pretend' => false` in config. I'll mess with this and get back to you.

Comment: I think that `Mail::pretend();` would "pretend" to send another email but wouldn't cancel the current email. Am I right? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#mail-and-local-development

Comment: It would turn on "pretend" mode. The next lines in the `sendSwiftMessage` check for that mode and skip the send.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Didn't read all of the code above. Sounds like this is probably the only way to do it. But I don't think I want to be messing with changing a global setting just for one email. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Well, it's only going to turn it on for the one pageview. It doesn't change the overall config setting for the application. You could throw an exception instead, if you want.

Comment: How could i get the to params. ie how can i get the email of the person recieving the email?